# Formik handleChange - use hooks

Tags: react-native, formik

before installing Formik, my input looked like so:

```
         const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
         ....

         <View style={styles.profileEditContainer__top}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.profileEditContainer__form}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            placeholder="Enter what you want to create.."
            placeholderTextColor={Colors.formPlaceHolderDefault}
            name="search"
            type="search"
            value={search}
            onChangeText={(e) => setSearch(e)}
            autoCorrect={false}
            defaultValue={search}
          />
          <Button
            disabled={!search}
            title="Create"
            onPress={(e) => {
              createNewCar(e);
            }}
          />
        </View>
```

in `onChangeText`, I would set every character I typed to a state prop called `search`. With every key that I typed, an API called would be made to get some data from the db.

for example:

if I typed `h` into the input, the db would return 2 cars `honda, hyundai`

I read that Formik can simplify a lot of the form setup in React, so I downloaded it, however, the `handleChange` prop from Formik wants to keep track of `values.search`

```
         <Formik
          initialValues={{
            search,
          }}
          onSubmit={(values) => {
            console.log('values', values);
          }}>
          {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, values }) => (
            <View style={styles.profileEditContainer__top}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.profileEditContainer__form}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                placeholder="Enter what you want to create.."
                placeholderTextColor={Colors.formPlaceHolderDefault}
                autoCorrect={false}
                value={values.search}
                onChangeText={(e) => {
                  handleChange(values.search);
                  setSearch(e);
                }}
              />
              <Button
                disabled={!search}
                title="Create"
                onPress={handleSubmit}
              />
            </View>
          )}
        </Formik>
```

Now I can't type into the form because `value` is pointing at `values.search` instead of `search` like it did originally.

**Question**

How do I fire `setSearch` in `onChangeText` but also add `search` into the formik `values` prop?

Answer (score 5):

you can make use of `setFieldValue('search', e.target.value)` instead of handleChange() change the code to the following:

```
<Formik
      initialValues={{
        search,
      }}
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        console.log('values', values);
      }}>
      {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, values, setFieldValue }) => (
        <View style={styles.profileEditContainer__top}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.profileEditContainer__form}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            placeholder="Enter what you want to create.."
            placeholderTextColor={Colors.formPlaceHolderDefault}
            autoCorrect={false}
            value={values.search}
            onChangeText={(e) => {
              //handleChange(values.search);
              setFieldValue('search', e.target.value)

              setSearch(e);
            }}
          />
          <Button
            disabled={!search}
            title="Create"
            onPress={handleSubmit}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this based on their documentation:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { Formik } from 'formik';
 import { Button, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
 
 export const MyReactNativeForm = props => (
   <Formik
     initialValues={{ email: '' }}
     onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
   >
     {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
       <View>
         <TextInput
           onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
           onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
           value={values.email}
         />
         <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
       </View>
     )}
   </Formik>
 );
```